# where is the Java stack allocated?

Tags: java

I have noted the following from a website: The JVM HotSpot memory is split between 3 memory spaces:

- The Java Heap
- The PermGen (permanent generation) space
- The Native Heap (C-Heap)

Where is the stack allocated in hotSpot JVM? In native heap?

update:
another reference info:
For a 64-bit VM, the C-Heap capacity = Physical server total RAM & virtual memory – Java Heap - PermGen

Comment: Wherever the implementation allocates it...

Comment: Keep in mind that Java code can be running under a JIT compiler, which also might change that.

Comment: The stack can be allocated to any of the three memory spaces, depending on the implementation of the JVM (i.e. Oracle and Apple develop different implementations of Java).

Comment: What happens for hotSpot jvm? Many thanks to you

Comment: In C 32-bity or 64-bit, the heap is limited by the virtual memory the OS allows. The physical memory is not important, thus the name "virtual" ;)

Comment: @Stephen has  the correct answer and deserves the bounty, all known impl. by now (- the ancient solaris green threads) use the native/hardware stack. Anything else would be borderline retarded. That creates a minor issue w/ stack overflow's in native code that can crash the JVM.

Comment: @Vulcan, non of the above is true, in sun's java there is a special option to specify the default stack size `-Xss`

Comment: @jiafu, the three pieces of memory you list are all **heap**, none of them is stack. Stacks use the hardware, otherwise any java implementation will terrible.

Comment: Stacks use the hardware? what's your mean? From all answers, I can't understand where stack allocated . Tanks

Comment: @jaifu - as I said in comments below "stacks use hardware" is a red-herring.

Comment: in hotspot JVM each java Thread has 320KB native memory allocated as stack by default. Not much 'java stuff' goes on the stack though - local primitives and local object references (but not the objects themselves they go on heap - unless using new-fangled escape analysis) .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer is:

1. It is implementation dependent.
2. In the implementation I looked at, the thread stack allocation was handled by the standard C native thread library, and it looked like the library was going to the OS to allocate a memory segment for the stack.  So "none of the above".
3. You can confirm this by delving into the OpenJDK source code relevant to your platform.

**UPDATE**

From an old question, here is the snippet of code from `pthread_create` that requests the allocation of the thread stack.  This method *used* by the JVM thread implementation to create the native thread.

```
 mmap(0, attr.__stacksize, 
     PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, 
     MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)
```

As you can see, it just uses the `mmap` system call to request a memory segment from the operating system.  As I said in a comment, this is NOT the regular Java heap, NOT the Permgen heap, and NOT the C native heap.  It is a segment of memory specifically requested from the operating system.

For reference, here's a link to the [mmap syscall manual entry](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).

---

> update: another reference info: For a 64-bit VM, the C-Heap capacity = Physical server total RAM & virtual memory – Java Heap - PermGen

IMO, that is an oversimplification.  (And please provide a link to where you found this information ... so that we can read it in its original form.)

Comment: if So. Can I think java thread will be allocated in native heap?  Due to both JVM heap and PermGen space has be used for special use.

Comment: You can also think nothing of it, it's an implementation detail.

Comment: I am interesting on it. nothing of it. where it is?

Comment: @jiafu - you can think whatever you like. However, I don't have any evidence of what you are saying.  Like I said in my answer, in the case I looked at the thread stack is NOT allocated in regular heap, NOT allocated in permgen, and NOT allocated in the C native heap.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, it's not impl. detail - although you can speculate that it can be, anything but the hardware stack is just stupid.

Comment: @jiafu, PermGen is just a heap area, it's treated specially by the GC b/c it's very unlikely to be freed - in order to be free some classes+classloader had to be 'unloaded'.

Comment: @bestsss - In fact, there is nothing "hardware stack" specific about the way that the memory is allocated.  See the code snippet.

Comment: @StephenC, mmap will allocate memory to the process and then sets the stack pointer in it - that's the hardware part I was referring to. Of course the memory belongs to the process. It uses mmap since it doesn't actually allocate resident memory  - the physical memory is allocated to the process on page fault.

Comment: then sets - the `pthread` lib sets. Technically the address space doesn't have C heap, java heap, it's just address space.

Comment: @bestsss - so, in fact, your comment about hardware is actually a red-herring.  This question is about allocation of memory for thread stacks ... not about how it is used.

Comment: @bestsss - and your comment about how/when physical memory gets associated with the virtual addresses is also a red-herring.  (As well as being an implementation strategy that is not necessarily followed in all operating systems.)

Comment: impl. strategy: mmap is not the standard for memory allocation either - windows is not posix and doesn't have it, windows doesn't use pthreads either. The comment refers to the case when mmap is used and why pthreads uses it. The memory for the thread stack is just memory belonging to the process and the hardware stack pointer actually points to it. You can even use a standard malloc for the stack but it would be less efficient and won't be protected from stackoverflows. mmap ensures that invalid addresses will be handled properly, yet in all OS the stackpointer is set within the block.

Comment: @bestsss - if I remember correctly, setting the "red zone" at the end of the stack was done using another syscall.  And the SP and what it is set to is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @bestsss - yes, pthread_create *could* use the regular C heap, but it didn't in the version I looked at.  I imagine that's because `malloc` wouldn't give a page-aligned segment, and that would make setting page access permissions for the red-zone difficult.

Comment: yes, pthread's uses `mprotect` but using malloc would require protecting from both sides to prevent memory corruption and in case of ia64 - the guard/red zone is in the middle as it has 2 fancy stacks per thread, one for registers, one for data growing towards each other.

Comment: http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=HotSpot+VM:+3+memory+spaces&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjavaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com%2F2011%2F08%2Fjava-heap-space-hotspot-vm.html&ei=OlblT56ZJKq5iQez8thY&usg=AFQjCNFb83XlYx7FTRpLhEOrNUtPwbew8g&cad=rjt

Comment: @jiafu - Hmmmm ... yes ... that article is definitely oversimplified, and plain wrong in some areas.  For instance on 32 bit Windows or Linux, the max available native space is not 4G minus something. A significant part of the address space is reserved for other things.  (Up to 2Gb, depending on the OS.)

Answer (score -1):

If you can find access to those things in any which way, the second Sun (or Oracle it is now adays?) will put out a patch quickly.

Being able to access those sorts of things is a HUGE security risk.  A lot of systems for big companies used Java.  To leave a hole where it is possible to track down allocation space wouldnt be possible.

as above, MMAP will allocate space and return it for the program and space requirements needed.  I do a lot of stuff with MMAP almost every day.

Maybe because i think a bit darker in how things can be used (to better protect my systems), pretty sure there would be a hot fix for it to cancel out your work, or you have Team America World Police knocking at your door suspecting you of foul acts, and in the process seize all your equipment.